# Using JWT with single, hard-coded user without database

Tags: .net, rest, web, jwt

I have a WEB API written in .NET 5.0.
I want to use JWT in there, but there will be only one user and I don't really want to use EF Core in this project - I have second API and some SQL table-valued functions.

So, my question is - what would be the best way for me to store and authenticate this user? Do I need to use custom UserManager and UserStores or could I only go for storing user credentials encrypted in appconfig?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one user you can choose to store it in Web.config as a app setting like so

```
<add key="UserName" value="UserName" />
<add key="Password" value="Password" />
```

But I wouldn't know why you want only one hardcoded user, is it then necessery to even make a user?